# Chrome allowed too many parallel requests to the same resource at the same time

Tags: https, request, google-chrome-devtools, http2, http-1.1

Please see the below Image, all the requests were sent to the same server almost at the same time.

Chrome version is 86.0.4240.183.

[image]

That's very weird, I thought there was a maximum of six TCP connections per host. In my opinion, how the requests were sent should be like the below Image

[image]

How could Chrome not to block/stall when making multiple requests, can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of the benefits of HTTP/2 that is called multiplexing.

HTTP/1.1 is sort of like buying a single item at a grocery store, taking it back home, going back to the store for the next item you need, and repeating until your pantry is fully stocked. Multiplexing gives you a shopping cart so you can pick up everything you need in one trip.